# Imprimir os valores de uma pilha

Tags: c++, stack

Eu tenho que fazer um código que imprima os todos valores de uma pilha na ordem oposta em que eles foram inseridos, só que eu só consigo imprimir um valor por vez, cada vez que eu queira ver o valor anterior eu tenho que selecionar a opção 8 no meu programa.

Obs.: Minha pilha é uma classe derivada da lista
Aqui esta o código:

lista.h

```
#include <string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Nodo //nodos para listas duplamente encadeadas
{
    string valor;
    Nodo *anterior;
    Nodo *proximo;
};

#ifndef LISTA_H
#define LISTA_H
class Lista
{
public:
    Lista(){};
    Lista(Nodo *primeiro);

    void insereFim(Nodo *novo);
    void insereInicio(Nodo *novo);
    void insereAntes(Nodo *novo, Nodo *ref);
    void insereDepois(Nodo *novo, Nodo *ref);
    void removeInicio();
    void removeFim();
    void removeEscolhe(Nodo *n);
    void vetore (Nodo*n, int ref);

protected:
    Nodo *inicio;
    Nodo *fim;
    int tamanho;
    int vetor;

};

#endif
```

pilha.h

```
#include"lista.h"
#ifndef PILHA_H
#define PILHA_H

class pilha 
{
public:
    pilha(){};
    pilha(Nodo *p);
    void push(Nodo *novo); //insercao
    void pop(); //remocao
    Nodo *top(); //tamanho
    void retorna();
    //bool empty();

private:
    Nodo *topo;
    int tamanho;
};

#endif PILHA_H`
```

pilha.cpp

```
#include"pilhas.h"

pilha::pilha(Nodo *p)
{
    p->anterior = NULL;
    p->proximo = NULL;

    topo = p;
    tamanho = 1;
};

Nodo *pilha::top()
{
    return topo;
};

void pilha::push(Nodo *novo)
{    
    novo ->proximo =NULL;
    novo->anterior =topo;    

    topo = novo;
    tamanho++;
};

void pilha::pop()
{
    if(tamanho == 0)

        cout << "Impossivel remover";
    else if(tamanho ==1)
    {
        topo =NULL;
        tamanho=0;
    }
    else
    {
        topo = topo -> anterior;
        tamanho--;
    }
};

void pilha::retorna()
{
    if(tamanho == 0)
    {
        cout << "Não há caminho" << endl;
    }
    else if(tamanho <= 1) 
    {

        do{

            cout << "   " << topo->valor << endl; 
            topo = topo -> anterior;
            tamanho--;

        }while(tamanho==NULL);

    }
};
```

Main .cpp

```
#include"pilhas.h"

int main()
{
    //Criando as 4 salas
    Nodo n1, n2, n3 , n4;
    pilha Salas;
    int N;
    bool S=false;
    n1.valor="Calabouco";
    n2.valor="Hall";
    n3.valor="Quartos";
    n4.valor="Cozinha";

    //Pergunta pra onde quer ir
    while (!S)
    {
        cout << "Escolha um local " <<endl;
        cout << "1-Calabouco" << endl;
        cout << "2-Hall" <<endl;
        cout << "3-Quartos" << endl;
        cout << "4-Cozinha" << endl;
        cout << "7-Sair" << endl;
        cout << "8-Mostrar caminho de Volta" << endl;
        cin >> N;

        switch (N)
        {

        case 1:
            Salas.push(&n1);
            cout << n1.valor << endl;

            break;
        case 2:
            Salas.push(&n2);
            cout << n2.valor << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            Salas.push(&n3);
            cout << n3.valor << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            Salas.push(&n4);
            cout << n4.valor << endl;
            break;
        case 7:
            S=true;
            break;
        case 8://Saida 
            Salas.retorna();

            break;
        default:
            cout << "Essa sala nao existe" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: na funcao retorna nao seria do {...} while (tamanho != 0); ?

Comment: Era sim, valeu meu. Mas eu to tendo um problema que quando o tamanho chega a 0 o while trava.

Comment: Programas em português ficam tão feios.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é o seguinte:

Como tu inicializa o atributo **tamanho** da classe **pilha** como 1 e sempre que insere na pilha (`push()`) é incrementado mais 1 ao atributo tamanho, então, se você adicionar 5 elementos o atributo tamanho será igual a 6. Logo, o `DO-WHILE` dentro do método `retorna()` deverá ter condição de parada (`tamanho > 1`).

Outra solução é inicializar o tamanho com 0 e coloca a condição de parada como (`tamanho > 0`), que acredito ser mais prudente já a pilha inicia vazia.